# How to add reminder details to Calendar- Android

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, reminders

I'm a newbie in Android and i need some help in setting up a calendar for my application. Calendar is one of the four parts i have in my App. others include setting up a reminder. Now what i need is, i want those reminders to be shown in the calendar on that particular day. For example if i had set a reminder on May 4th, 2014 then the calendar on May 4th should show this reminder.

- To be precise it should be something similar to the calendar shown in 'myHomework'.
- when we click on a date, there should be a list of messages under the calendar showing what all reminders were setup on that day.

[image: sample screenshot from myHomework]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d1hwvnnkb0v1bo.cloudfront.net/content/art/app/screenshots/myhomework_screenshot31.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the android intent to invoke default calender intent of calender. Use the code below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
startActivity(intent);
```

you can also use putExtra in this

```
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,endTime);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Addy's Birthday");
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "This is a sample description");
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My Guest House");
```

hope this helps